# Firebase and Google Analytics - missing measurementId?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

I have a few Firebase projects on which I use Firestore and Firebase Storage.

I want to start using Google Analytics and I see [this page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/get-started) with all the instructions. The key setting being the parameter "measurementId".
So, following the instructions, I go to my project settings and find the config snippet but unlike in the instructions it does NOT contain this parameter...

[image]

How do I generate it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution came from Firebase support, my project needed to be "relinked" to Google Analytics.

> **Relink your Firebase project to a Mobile App property**
>
> If you had
>   previously linked your Firebase project with your Analytics account
>   but are no longer able to locate your Firebase project in Analytics:
>
> 1. Open your Firebase project.
> 2. Open Project settings > Integrations.
> 3. Click the Analytics card to link Analytics to your project.

More details [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9289234?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this also. It seems there is a bug in the website. Set up [Firebase CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#project_aliases) and run the following command.

```
firebase --project <project-name> apps:sdkconfig
```

It should output something like the following:

```
? Select the app to get the configuration data: Web - 1:686396208177:web:5119a766dc890b7d671110 (WEB)
✔ Downloading configuration data of your Firebase WEB app
// Copy and paste this into your JavaScript code to initialize the Firebase SDK.
// You will also need to load the Firebase SDK.
// See https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup for more details.

firebase.initializeApp({
  // ... snip ...
  "measurementId": "redacted"
});
```

It includes `measurementId`.

Comment: It show exactly the same as in the Firebase console, without the measurementId

Comment: Hmm, that’s super weird. Maybe your project is in a weird state. This definitely seems like a bug. I’d try contacting support.

Comment: I just created a ticket to Firestore support, will post their answer when I get it